# Sort a vector of objects

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm working with a simple c++ program, with this class:
(I'm a very beginner programmer)

```
class Car{
private:
    string newBrand;
    int newMileage;
    int newYear;
    double newPrice;
```

(i didn't post the public classes)

```
bool sortByName(Car &CarVector) 
{ 
    return CarVector.getBrand() < CarVector.getBrand(); 
}
```

Main:

```
int main(){

    vector<Car> CarVector;
    ReadFile(CarVector);
    ListCar(CarVector);

    return 0;
}
```

LIst Car Functions, when i call the function "sort", to order my vector of objects by name:

```
void ListCar(vector<Car>&CarVector){

    int i, op;
    system("CLS");

    sort(CarVector.begin(), CarVector.end(), sortByName);

    cout << "MENU::CAR LIST BY NAME" << endl;
    cout << ":Brand: \t:Mileage: \t:Year: \t\t:Price:" << endl;

    for(i=0; i<CarVector.size();i++)
    {
        cout << CarVector[i].getBrand() << " \t\t";
        cout << CarVector[i].getMileage() << " \t\t";
        cout << CarVector[i].getYear() << " \t\t";
        cout << CarVector[i].getPrice() << " \t\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    do
    {
    cout << endl << "1.Back: ";
    cin >> op;
    }while(op!=1);
}
```

I think that this program is supposed to work. Can you help me finding the error? 
Best regards

Comment: Please describe your errors in your question

Comment: 1st: error C2197: 'bool (__cdecl *)(Car &)' : too many arguments for call
2nd: error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); s

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa As mentioned: [**in your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24120062/edit)

Comment: couple of suggestions: 1) remove "new" prefix from Car member names, 2) `sortByName` should be called `compareByBrand`, 3) sorting should happen outside of `ListCars` (note the name), e.g. in `main`, 4) don't do `system("CLS");`

Comment: @AndyT, thank's for the advices. One question, about the `system("Cls")`, why are you saying this? It's a bad way to implement the code?

Comment: just don't decide for user when to clear its console screen, there can be some valuable info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your compare function, you need to use **two parameters**: it should compare these objects with each other. Also, that's independent of any *vector* (it operates on *elements* of your vector), so you shouldn't name the arguments like that to avoid confusion.

So the function could look like this:

```
bool sortByName(Car &a, Car &b) 
{ 
    return a.getBrand() < b.getBrand(); 
}
```

Additionally, it's a good choice (but not always required) to add `const` to parameteres passed by reference in order to indicate that the function body doesn't modify them:

```
bool sortByName(const Car &a, const Car &b) 
{ 
    return a.getBrand() < b.getBrand(); 
}
```

But then it's necessary to put `const` at the end of the signature of the function `Car::getBrand()` in order to indicate that *that function* won't modify the object it operates on. This is called *const-correctness*. As mentioned before, that process is not always required (like when using `std::sort`) but it's a good style to have const-correctness.

Or you can use a lambda if your compiler supports it (you need to enable C++11 support):

```
std::sort(CarVector.begin(), CarVector.end(), [](const Car &a, const Car &b){
    return a.getBrand() < b.getBrand();
});
```

---

Note that if you're going to compare cars *always by name*, it makes sense to implement an `operator<` for your class. When doing that, you don't need to specify a compare function in the call to `std::sort`, as those objects are then simply compared like `a < b` instead of `yourFunction(a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool sortByName(Car &CarVector1,Car &CarVector2) 
{ 
    return CarVector1.getBrand() < CarVector2.getBrand(); 
}
```

use this sortByName

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass two Car Objects in `sortByName` method to compare two Objects as :

```
bool sortByName(Car &C1,Car &C2) 
{ 
    return C1.getBrand() < C2.getBrand(); 
}
```

Check this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for more detail

Comment: Yes operator has to be overload outside of class